# MSMQ triggers, are they different then using BeginPeek and EndPeek. C#

Tags: c#, triggers, msmq

I'm trying to implement MSMQ triggers. All the article I see for C# contains or describe it using BeginPeek or BeginReceive methods.

The following link contains VB code for triggers  and rules creation. It uses 
MSMQTriggerObjects,  which I can't find find for C#.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25310/Programatically-Creating-MSMQ-Triggers

I wish to use to know, if they are indeed same thing(BeginPeek and triggers), does that means BeginPeek is pooling type operation, as it keeps on checking queue, like we writing a method to peek queue via a thread with some sleep timer.

Comment: Acc. to article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703197(v=vs.85).aspx, c# devs are not allowed to use mqtrig.dll
Also acc. to this article https://www.slideshare.net/PeterREgli/msmq-microsoft-message-queueing, slide 10, MSMQ is not allowed in .Net. Am I right?